# ModalResult not acting inside of a component

Tags: delphi, components

Below you can see the code for a component that have inside a TPersistent class that allow me to assign some TCustomButtons (TButton or TBitBtn).

I place my component on a modal form and I assign the 2 buttons (OK and Cancel).
Normally when I press any of this buttons, my form should getting closed.

My question is why the form is not getting closed?

```
type
  TMyComp = class;
  TButtons = class;

  TMyComp = class(TComponent)
  private
    FButtons: TButtons;
    procedure SetButtons(Value: TButtons);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
 published 
    property Buttons: TButtons read FButtons write SetButtons;
 end;

 TButtons = class(TPersistent)
 private
   FOwner: TMyComp;
   FBtnOk: TCustomButton;
   FBtnCancel: TCustomButton;
   procedure SetCustomButton(Index: Integer; Value: TCustomButton);
   procedure BtnOkOnClick(Sender: TObject);
   procedure BtnCancelOnClick(Sender: TObject);
 protected
 public
   constructor Create(AOwner: TMyComp);  virtual;
   procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
 published
   property BtnOk: TCustomButton index 0 read FBtnOk write SetCustomButton;
   property BtnCancel: TCustomButton index 1 read FBtnCancel write SetCustomButton;
 end;

implementation

constructor TMyComp.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FButtons:= TButtons.Create(Self);
end;

destructor TMyComp.Destroy;
begin
  FButtons.Free;
  inherited;
end;

//------- TButtons ---------
constructor TButtons.Create(AOwner: TMyComp);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FOwner:= AOwner;
end;

procedure TButtons.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
begin
  if Source is TButtons then
    begin
      FBtnOk:= TButtons(Source).BtnOk;
      FBtnCancel:= TButtons(Source).BtnCancel;
    end
  else
    inherited Assign(Source);
end;

procedure TButtons.SetCustomButton(Index: Integer; Value: TCustomButton);
begin
  case Index of
    0: if FBtnOk <> Value then
      begin
        FBtnOk:= Value;

        if Assigned(FBtnOk) then
          begin
            //TBitBtn
            if (FBtnOk is TBitBtn) then
              (FBtnOk as TBitBtn).OnClick:= BtnOkOnClick;

            //TButton
            if (FBtnOk is TButton) then
              (FBtnOk as TButton).OnClick:= BtnOkOnClick;
          end;
      end;

    1: if FBtnCancel <> Value then
      begin
        FBtnCancel:= Value;

        if Assigned(FBtnCancel) then
          begin
            //TBitBtn
            if (FBtnCancel is TBitBtn) then
              (FBtnCancel as TBitBtn).OnClick:= BtnCancelOnClick;

            //TButton
            if (FBtnCancel is TButton) then
              (FBtnCancel as TButton).OnClick:= BtnCancelOnClick;
          end;
      end;
  end;

  if Assigned(Value) then Value.FreeNotification(FOwner);
end;

procedure TButtons.BtnCancelOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  showmessage('Cancel pressed!');

  if Sender is TButton then
    (Sender as TButton).ModalResult:= mrCancel;

  if Sender is TBitBtn then
    (Sender as TBitBtn).ModalResult:= mrCancel;
end;

procedure TButtons.BtnOkOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //do some input validations here...
  showmessage('Ok pressed!');

  if Sender is TButton then
    (Sender as TButton).ModalResult:= mrOk;

  if Sender is TBitBtn then
    (Sender as TBitBtn).ModalResult:= mrOk;
end;
```

Comment: A MCVE would mean we knew what your code was. Why are you setting event handlers for the buttons. Why not set ModalResult. It all looks a bit sketchy though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers/comments have explained why the code is not working - you are setting the button's `ModalResult` too late, so it is not propagating to the Form's `ModalResult` when you are expecting it to be.

I want to suggest an alternative implementation that also incorporates a solution, and addresses some other things your code is lacking:

```
type
  TButtons = class;

  TMyComp = class(TComponent)
  private
    FButtons: TButtons;
    procedure SetButtons(Value: TButtons);
  protected
    procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published 
    property Buttons: TButtons read FButtons write SetButtons;
  end;

  TButtons = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FOwner: TMyComp;
    FButtons: array[0..1] of TCustomButton;
    FClickEvents: array[0..1] of TNotifyEvent;
    function GetCustomButton(Index: Integer): TCustomButton;
    procedure SetCustomButton(Index: Integer; Value: TCustomButton);
    procedure BtnOkOnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BtnCancelOnClick(Sender: TObject);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TMyComp);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  published
    property BtnOk: TCustomButton index 0 read GetCustomButton write SetCustomButton;
    property BtnCancel: TCustomButton index 1 read GetCustomButton write SetCustomButton;
  end;

implementation

//------- TMyComp ---------
constructor TMyComp.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FButtons := TButtons.Create(Self);
end;

destructor TMyComp.Destroy;
begin
  FButtons.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyComp.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
var
  i: Index;
begin
  inherited;
  if Operation = opRemove then
  begin
    for i := Low(FButtons.FButtons) to High(FButtons.FButtons) do
    begin
      if AComponent = FButtons.FButtons[i] then
      begin
        FButtons.FButtons[i] := nil;
        FButtons.FClickEvents[i] := nil;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;      
end;

//------- TButtons ---------
constructor TButtons.Create(AOwner: TMyComp);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FOwner := AOwner;
end;

constructor TButtons.Destroy;
begin
  Assign(nil);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TButtons.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if Source = nil then
  begin
    for i to Low(FButtons) to High(FButtons) do
      SetCustomButton(i, nil);
  end
  else if Source is TButtons then
  begin
    for i to Low(FButtons) to High(FButtons) do
      SetCustomButton(i, TButtons(Source).FButtons[i]);
  end
  else
    inherited Assign(Source);
end;

function TButtons.GetCustomButton(Index: Integer): TCustomButton;
begin
  Result := FButtons[Index];
end;

type
  TCustomButtonAccess = class(TCustomButton)
  end;

procedure TButtons.SetCustomButton(Index: Integer; Value: TCustomButton);
begin
  if FButtons[Index] <> Value then
  begin
    if Assigned(FButtons[Index]) then
    begin
      TCustomButtonAccess(Value).OnClick := FClickEvents[Index];
      FClickEvents[Index] := nil;
      FButtons[Index].RemoveFreeNotification(FOwner);
    end;
    FButtons[Index] := Value;
    if Assigned(Value) then
    begin
      Value.FreeNotification(FOwner);
      FClickEvents[Index] := TCustomButtonAccess(Value).OnClick;
      case Index of
        0: TCustomButtonAccess(Value).OnClick := BtnOkOnClick;
        1: TCustomButtonAccess(Value).OnClick := BtnCancelOnClick;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TButtons.BtnOkOnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TCustomForm;
begin
  //do some input validations here...
  ShowMessage('Ok pressed!');
  Form := GetParentForm(TControl(Sender));
  if Form <> nil then
    Form.ModalResult := mrOk;
  // optional
  if Assigned(FClickEvents[0]) then
    FClickEvents[0](Sender);
end;

procedure TButtons.BtnCancelOnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TCustomForm;
begin
  ShowMessage('Cancel pressed!');
  Form := GetParentForm(TControl(Sender));
  if Form <> nil then
    Form.ModalResult := mrCancel;
  // optional
  if Assigned(FClickEvents[1]) then
    FClickEvents[1](Sender);
end;
```

Comment: `GetParentForm(TControl(Sender))` this was I was looking for... Well done Remy! Initially I've tried with `GetParentForm(Self)` but compliler ask me for a `TControl`. So like a solution, based on your answer I just used this code: `form:= GetParentForm(TControl(Sender));  if form <> nil then form.ModalResult:= mrOk;`

Answer (score 2):

A simpler reproduction case can be like this:

Create an application with two forms, remove second form from the auto-created forms list. Add a button on each form with the following click handlers.

In unit1:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  F: TForm;
begin
  F := TForm2.Create(nil);
  try
    F.ShowModal;
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;
end;
```

In unit2:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.ModalResult := mrOk;
end;
```

Run application, press button to launch the modal form. Press button on second form, the form does not close.

The reason the form is not closed is, the button's click handler is too late to set the modal result of the form.

You can see why it is too late from the code in `TCustomButton.Click;` in 'Vcl.StdCtrls.pas'. Comments are by me.

```
procedure TCustomButton.Click;
var
  Form: TCustomForm;
begin
  Form := GetParentForm(Self);
  if Form <> nil then Form.ModalResult := ModalResult; // this is where modal result is checked
  inherited Click;                                     // this is where your click handler is run
end;
```

You'd notice a second click closes the form. That's because the button's modal result is already set after the first click.

Comment: the weird think is that in the past I used many times this and it works! but in place of `Button1.ModalResult := mrOk` i used all the time `ModalResult := mrOk` and it works.

Comment: Anyhow, when I `SetCustomButton`, I can assign to the button a `ModalResult` value. But I have an input validation to made and if this validation failed, then I need to keep the form open... so how can I do this with my component structure?

Comment: @real - Yes of course, what a button's modal result does is to set form's modal result. You can set modal result of the form any time you like. You can see how to access the parent form in the last snippet in my answer. I removed that information from my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40324903/2) when I noticed you explicitly asked "why the form did not close".

Comment: You may want to ask a question about the second problem with a test case.

Comment: Partially your answer make me understand how `ModalResult` act, but it didn't solve my problem. As I explained in a comment, `GetParentForm(Self)` it's not working under component (Self is not recognized by compiler). `GetParentForm(TControl(Sender))` is in this case the final solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126999/discussion-between-realsofo-and-sertac-akyuz).

Comment: @Real - You already knew how to solve that problem. `(FBtnOk as TButton)` that's from your code, so you know what a typecast is when it is required. You could use the same typecast to call `GetParentForm` too. It's difficult to evaluate what you need when you don't ask for it. It seems that you needed someone else to write the code for you. Ask for it in the question then, don't only specifically ask *"why the form is not getting closed?"*.

Comment: Of course not. I did some trials before, but none of them succeeding. Let's not be childish...

Comment: @REALSOFO You clearly don't understand the word "childish" as evidenced by your comment that successfully demonstrates its meaning; but probably not in the way you expect. That aside your comment shows a complete lack of gratitude and disrespect to someone who made an effort to help you in spite of your failure to sufficiently describe your problem on the original question.

Answer (score -1):

In your event handler you're setting `ModalResult` of the button. A modal form closes when ***that form's*** `ModalResult` is set.

The purpose of a [button's `ModalResult`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton.ModalResult) is that the framework will set the ***parent form's*** `ModalResult` to the same value.

> Setting the button component's ModalResult property is an easy way to make clicking the button close a modal form. **When a button is clicked**, the ModalResult property of its parent form is set to the same value as the button's ModalResult property.
>   For example, if a dialog box has OK and Cancel buttons, their ModalResult properties could be set at design time to mrOk and mrCancel, respectively. At run time, clicking the OK button then changes the dialog's ModalResult property to mrOk, and clicking the Cancel button changes the dialog's ModalResult property to mrCancel. **Unless *further* processing** is required, **no OnClick event handlers are required** for the buttons.

So, basically what you're doing wrong is that you failed to predefine the `ModalResult` of the button. So:

- At the time the button is clicked, its `ModalResult` is still `mrNone`.
- And therefore doesn't change the form's `ModalResult`.
- (I suspect that if you click the button a second time it will behave as you expect.)

To resolve your problem, you have 2 options:

- Preferably set the `ModalResult` of the button sooner. There's no reason for a "Cancel" button to ***ever have*** a `ModalResult <> mrCancel`. That's why it's usually streamed in the DFM.
- If you absolutely must use the event handler; set the ***form's*** `ModalResult`.